# pyspark - creating dataframes using sqlCtx.load() from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I get an error while creating a dataframe in pyspark. Pls let me know how to fix it. I am learning pyspark commands through Coursera.

Here are the commands that I used:

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark -- packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0

this seemed to work fine.

Once in the shell,  when I tried:

```
yelp_df = sqlCtx.load(source = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
               header = 'true',
               inferSchema = 'true',
               path ='file:///usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv')
```

I get the following error:

> Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()
>
> 3 header = 'true',
>
> 4 inferSchema = 'true',
>
> ----> 5 path = 'file:///usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv')
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in load(self, path, source, schema, **options)
>
> 480 self._sc._gateway._gateway_client)
>
> 481 if schema is None:
>
> --> 482 df = self._ssql_ctx.load(source, joptions)
>
> 483 else:
>
> 484 if not isinstance(schema, StructType):
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in **call**(self, *args)
>
> 536 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
>
> 537 return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
>
> --> 538 self.target_id, self.name)

Comment: your traceback log does not seem complete, what is the final error ?

Comment: The dump is too long . I am adding some more here:The entire dump is here--    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Comment: I guess the main part of error listing is: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at tCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.jav

Answer (score 0):

Load it as a text file, split according to your delimiter ',' then convert to dataframe. With sc being your spark context,

```
sc.textFile('file:///usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv').map(lambda row:row.split(',')).toDF
```